# Easy way to encrypt and decrypt uploaded FILE to folder using AngularJS and PHP Framework

Tags: php, angularjs, encryption, upload

I'am trying to find a simple solution for encrypting and decrypting file such as .pdf. I do research and test codes for this like crypto.js but I dont understand how to do it.
Can anyone help me to how to do this?

Lot of Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just follow this link. I used php for encryption.
[Aescrypt](https://forums.packetizer.com/viewtopic.php?f=72&t=403)